# Python - Defining a variable based on appearing more than one time within groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following data set and im trying to build a third variable by counting how many times a skill appear across the set, for example if they appear in group 1 three times we still count as one.I'm new to python and im not so sure where to start.

```
Group               Skill
  1                Windows
  1                Excel
  2                Windows                
  2                Java
  3                Windows
  3                Python
  4                Python
  4                SAS
```

What I am trying to achieve is, if a skill appear only in one group we call sector-specific, in more than one but less then 2 cross-sector and in more than 2 transversal. That may be times the same skill appear in the same group twice, however i still want to call only one time.

Then the final result would be:

```
Group               Skill               Type
  1                Windows            Transversal
  1                Excel              Sector-specific
  2                Windows            Transversal    
  2                Java               Sector-Specific
  3                Windows            Transversal
  3                Python             Cros-Sector
  4                Python             Cros-Sector
  4                SAS                Sector-specific
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) fot number of unique values per groups with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return Series with same size as original `DataFrame` and last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`, all unmatched values generate `NaN`s, so add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace it:

```
d = {1:'Sector-specific', 2:'Cros-Sector'}
df['Type'] = df.groupby('Skill')['Group'].transform('nunique').map(d).fillna('Transversal')
print (df)
   Group    Skill             Type
0      1  Windows      Transversal
1      1    Excel  Sector-specific
2      2  Windows      Transversal
3      2     Java  Sector-specific
4      3  Windows      Transversal
5      3   Python      Cros-Sector
6      4   Python      Cros-Sector
7      4      SAS  Sector-specific
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby('Skill')['Group'].transform('nunique'))
0    3
1    1
2    3
3    1
4    3
5    2
6    2
7    1
Name: Group, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @jezsrael , tks your solution seems as us usual very elegant. I am taking a python programming course at uni hopefully I will learn the basics properly and one day be able to help others like you always do.